# Are these old car models legit sets or MOCs?

Tags: set-identification

[image]Are these 4 historic car models legit sets or MOCs? If official sets do you know the set numbers?

How can I add more pictures then one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are indeed legit sets of the 70's.

[390-2: 1913 Cadillac](https://brickset.com/sets/390-2/1913-Cadillac)
[image]
[391-1: 1926 Renault](https://brickset.com/sets/391-1/1926-Renault)
[image]
[395-1: 1909 Rolls-Royce](https://brickset.com/sets/395-1/1909-Rolls-Royce)
[image]

Only the red car in the top right looks like a MOC version of the red Cadillac  set